# Defining array as global in case of multi file embedded project

Tags: arrays, embedded, global, mplab-c18

I've been trying to declare an array as global in mplab c18 and never found much success. Is there any possible way to access the array elements, or can we declare the array as global /extern and access from other source files.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array in one file

```
    char chMyArray[50];
```

And then in other files you can access it by

```
    extern char chMyArray[];
```

Its important that when you do the extern, you do not put how many spaces are in the array.
Using [] is fine.